# Sound malfunctioning in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, user-accounts, sound-card

I have a computer which is shared by two users, each one with his own user account.

For some time now, it looks like Windows starts pre-loading applications that the user had running in the previous session or that are loaded at boot, to make it faster.

After upgrading to `10.0.17763 Build 17763` my `Windows 10` box, my dedicated sound card seems to be "reserved" by the first user prompting in the login screen.
For example if user `A` is prompted in the logging screen and instead of that one, user `B` logs in with his account, he won't be able to play any sound unless `A` logs out. (Either really logging out or rebooting, because then user `B` will be the first one prompted then)

Is anyone facing this issue too? Is there any workaround I am ignoring besides telling Windows *not to pre-load applications*?

Comment: You can uninstall the application that does not appear to be compatible with 1809.  It would an application that is relevant to your sound device.  You might reinstall the drivers if uninstalling the application removes the drivers (which might or might not be compatible with 1809)

Comment: That might be the sound card drivers... so I think there must be another way out of this...

Comment: There is you install compatible drivers or revert back to 1803.